# Updated rails 3 to 4 wont look through gems assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I step on strange issue. I have bootstrap-sass gem(and some other js aswell). When im trying to access any page im getting

```
File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-responsive.

Load paths:
  /Users/alex/Projects/feedbackhunter/app/assets/images
  /Users/alex/Projects/feedbackhunter/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/alex/Projects/feedbackhunter/app/assets/stylesheets
```

As load paths says, rails wont look through bootstrap-sass gem assets, where all these files situated. What am i doin wrong?

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

# in production environments by default.

gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
#end

gem 'activeresource'


gem 'mysql2'     #gem to connect mysql dbs from mail server
gem "jquery-rails", "~> 2.3.0"
gem "thin", ">= 1.5.0"
gem 'mongoid', '~> 4', github: 'mongoid/mongoid'
gem 'bson_ext'
gem "bson", "~> 2.0.0.rc3"
gem "haml-rails", ">= 0.4"
gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.12.2", :group => [:development, :test]
gem "database_cleaner", ">= 1.0.0.RC1", :group => :test
gem 'mongoid-rspec', '>= 1.6.0', github: 'evansagge/mongoid-rspec', :group => :test

gem "email_spec", ">= 1.4.0", :group => :test
gem "cucumber-rails", ">= 1.3.1", :group => :test, :require => false
gem "launchy", ">= 2.2.0", :group => :test
gem "capybara", ">= 2.0.3", :group => :test
gem "factory_girl_rails", ">= 4.2.0", :group => [:development, :test]
gem "bootstrap-sass", ">= 2.3.0.0"
gem "sendgrid", ">= 1.0.1"
gem "devise"
gem "quiet_assets", ">= 1.0.2", :group => :development
gem "better_errors", ">= 0.7.2", :group => :development
gem "binding_of_caller", ">= 0.7.1", :group => :development#, :platforms => [:mri_19, :rbx]
gem 'meta_request', :group => :development
gem 'inherited_resources'
gem 'i18n-js'
gem 'awesome_print'
gem 'mail'
gem 'httparty'
gem 'protected_attributes' # https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes

gem 'actionpack-action_caching' # https://github.com/rails/actionpack-action_caching

gem 'rails-observers' # https://github.com/rails/rails-observers

gem 'formtastic-bootstrap'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'slim'
gem 'sinatra', :require => nil
gem 'sidetiq'
#gem 'activeadmin-mongoid', github: 'elia/activeadmin-mongoid', branch: 'active-admin-spec-suite'
#gem 'activeadmin', '~> 0.5.1'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
gem 'sidekiq-failures'
gem 'redis-semaphore'
gem 'bootstrap-switch-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails', :git => 'git@bitbucket.org:feedbackhunter/bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails.git'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'mechanize'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'best_in_place'
gem 'business_time'

gem 'lazy_high_charts'
gem 'statsample'
gem 'will_paginate_mongoid'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'
gem 'websocket-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-tour-rails'
gem "alertify-rails"
gem 'rails-i18n', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'capistrano'
#gem 'capistrano_colors'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'savon', "~> 2.3.0"
gem 'httpclient'
gem 'tire'
```

Comment: Can you paste the content of your Gemfile? The gem group `assets` has been removed in Rails 4. (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-2-to-rails-4-0-gemfile)

Comment: i have removed assets. Updated my question with gemfile

Comment: Have you restarted your app after running bundle install with the changes to your gemfile?

Comment: Sure. I'm not that new to rails. Updated gems to work with rails4(mongoid, bson)